# How can I stop the 'menu bar' appearing when using VMware on a Mac?

Tags: macos, vmware-fusion

When using running an Ubuntu guest using VMware Fusion (Mac OS X is the host), if I hover near the top of the screen, Mac OS X's 'menu bar' appears, which is not what I want. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**vmware fusion 3**

1. select your vm from the vm library.
2. go to 'view' menu, then to 'full screen title bar'.
3. select 'always hide'.

now when you go into full screen mode, no menu bars will appear.